# How to redirect method calls in python?

Tags: python, oop

I understand that you can use `__getattr__()` to access attributes that don't exist as that class's attributes. However I wanted to do the same thing with functions.

I read that python treats attributes and methods the same, so you use the `__getattr__()` for methods aswell. Is this true?

```
class container:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        ##Don't know the code to put here vv
        result = getattr(self.data, item)


class data:
    def printHello(self):
        print("hello")

    def printString(self, string):
        print(string)

def main():
    someData = data()
    someContainer = container(someData)
    someContainer.printString("sup")

main()
```

Aim: I want to be able to write `container.printHello()` and have it invoke `container.data.printHello()`. I would also want a solution that would enable to pass parameters to `printString()` aswell. How would I go about doing this?

NOTE: This is a simplification. In reality I have a huge number of methods that I am constantly adding and removing and changing method names as I develop my program

Comment: Why is it such an issue to call `container.data` instead of just `container`? The most pythonic method for doing this is the one that you've already suggested: to just directly call the function. It's much clearer what is actually happening this way, and a lot less confusing to debug.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth I tend to agree, even more worrying is a class with 100s of methods that are constantly changing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pretty much have it, you just need to *return* what you had.

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.data, attr)

class Data:
    def print_hello(self):
        print("hello")

    def print_string(self, string):
        print(string)


Container(Data()).print_hello()
Container(Data()).print_string('foo')
```

Comment: This example is a simplification, so that answers address the core issue, and it's easier for others to read. In reality I have close to 100 methods and counting. I can't really do this for a class, that I am constantly adding and removing methods

Comment: I just realized I didn't have an issue with the implementation, I just forgot to return a value from def __getattr__(), which was why I was getting an error. Thanks, kind of a stupid error on my part.

Comment: While this answer *does* answer the asked question, I would strongly hazard against using this for the purpose mentioned in the question. this kind of thing can make debugging a nightmare, especially if the call stack gets too deep.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth I'm not familiar with how getattr works, but why would there be a call stack here? Also do you have another alternative that mitigates the issues you stated?

Comment: @user5423 they mean the call stack when you actually use `some_container_instance.print_hello()` or any other proxied method. It will make debugging more confusing, that is definitely something to weigh here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot return your result? It's works for me:

```
def __getattr__(self, item): 
    return getattr(self.data, item)
```

Comment: yh, I just figured that out. I've never used getattr, and didn't know python treats attributes and methods the same. So i thought the error was with the function I have never used. Turns out it was a lot more basic than that

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is return the attribute you found.

```
"""
Tests

>>> c = container(data())
>>> c.printHello()
hello
>>> c.printString("Hello World")
Hello World
>>> c.printGarbage('Hello World')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cont.py", line 19, in __getattr__
    result = getattr(self.data, item)
AttributeError: 'data' object has no attribute 'printGarbage'
"""

import functools

class container:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        result = getattr(self.data, item)
        return result

class data:
    def printHello(self):
        print("hello")

    def printString(self, string):
        print(string)
```